# How to find the roots of a polynomial within a given interval

Tags: scilab, polynomials

I want to write a function with inputs of a polynomial (p), and a range (a, b), which gives the number of the roots of a polynomial in this range. But I don't know how to set the range in the function.

```
x=poly(0,"x")
a = 0;
b = 5;
p=-6+11*x-6*x^2+x^3

function [n_roots] = numroots (p,a,b)
    rootn = roots(p)
//todo
    n_roots = length(rootn)
endfunction
```

The next step will be represent the polynomial and the roots in a graph.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should select which roots are in the range after the calculation of the roots. Notice that the roots should be real numbers if you want to classified them in a range.

```
function [n_roots] = numroots(p,a,b)
    rootn = roots(p)
    rootn = rootn(find(real(rootn) > a & real(rootn) < b))
    n_roots = length(rootn)
endfunction
```